# mocha / sinon stub restore not working

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

My first node test script. I'm using Mocha and Sinon to test a function which ultimately sends to a queue. Node v8.1.3, Mocha 5.0.2, sinon 4.4.2.

```
var assert = require('assert');
var sinon = require('sinon');
var uut = require('../util');
var stub;

describe('processWantedItemToQueue', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      stub = sinon.stub(uut, 'processWantedItemToQueue').returns(true);
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      uut.processWantedItemToQueue.restore();
    });

    it('should not push the item to the queue', function() {
      assert.equal(uut.processWantedItemToValidQueue("a", "q1"), false);
    });

    it('should push the item to the queue', function() {
      assert.equal(uut.processWantedItemToValidQueue("a", "aws"), true);
    });
});
```

This is my output:

```
> mocha
  processWantedItemToQueue
ignoring queue q1
    ✓ should not push the item to the queue
    1) should push the item to the queue


  1 passing (34ms)
  1 failing

  1) processWantedItemToQueue
       should push the item to the queue:
     ReferenceError: processWantedItemToQueue is not defined
      at Object.processWantedItemToValidQueue (util.js:36:20)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/test.js:20:24)
```

I've misunderstood something about stubs. Why isn't my second test finding the stub?

My util.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  processWantedItem: function(item) {
  ...
  },
  processWantedItemToQueue: function(item, queue) {
  ...
  },
  processWantedItemToValidQueue: function(item, queue) {
  ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this isn't an issue with your stub, but an issue with your implementation of `processWantedItemToValidQueue`; most likely you're only actually trying to call `processWantedItemToQueue` in the second case, but `processWantedItemToQueue` as you've defined it won't be in the scope of the other function. To be sure, though, you'd have to show your implementation of `processWantedItemToValidQueue`.

Comment: I'd just come to the same thought. Moving my uut functions to a module so I could export them for testing left them invisible in the module. prefixing with this. fixed it. Thanks.